# Need to find files with multiples arguments in bash

Tags: bash, find

I've done this atm, I need to find in the main directory and in the sub-directory everything starting with the letter 'a', every files ending with 'z' and every files starting with 'z' and ending with 'a!'.
`find . -name "a*" | find . "*z" -type f | find . "z*a!" -type f`
I tried to be as clear as possible, sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: The pipe does not make sense. `find` does not read from stdin, so no matter what you are doing, it does not make sense to pipe anything into `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f \( -name 'a*' -or -name '*z' -or -name 'z*a!' \)
```

Use `-o` instead of `-or` for POSIX compliance.

If you really want to also find links, directories, pipes etc. starting with `a` but only files matching the remaining conditions, you can do

```
find . -name 'a*' -or -type f \(-name '*z' -or -name 'z*a!' \)
```

Comment: This will not catch directories or links or anything else than a file starting with `a`. The OP is: _everything starting with the letter 'a'_. And their attempt confirms this.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Updated. I thought it was just an imprecise specification.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

```bash
find . -name 'a*' -o -type f \( -name '*z' -o -name 'z*a!' \)
```

Explanations:

The `find` logical operators are `-a` (AND) and `-o` (OR). You use them to combine elementary tests. Note that because of operator's precedence you sometimes need parentheses and that they must be escaped (with `\`) to prevent their interpretation by the shell. Your test is:

- *everything starting with the letter 'a'*: `-name 'a*'`.
- *every files ending with 'z'*: `-type f -a -name '*z'`.
- *every files starting with 'z' and ending with 'a!'*: `-type f -a -name 'z*a!'`.

So the complete test could be:

```
-name 'a*' -o \( -type f -a -name '*z' \) -o \( -type f -a -name 'z*a!' \)
```

As `-a` is the default we can omit it, and as `-type f` (file) is common to the two last terms of the disjunction we can factor it:

```
-name 'a*' -o -type f \( -name '*z' -o -name 'z*a!' \)
```